# Copy Data from one hbase table to another

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hive

I have created one table hivetest which also create the table in hbase with name of 'hbasetest'. Now I want to copy 'hbasetest' data into another hbase table(say logdata) with the same schema. So, can anyone help me how do copy the data from 'hbasetest' to 'logdata' without using the hive.

```
CREATE TABLE hivetest(cookie string, timespent string, pageviews string, visit string, logdate string) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = "m:timespent, m:pageviews, m:visit, m:logdate")
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "hbasetest");
```

**Updated question :**

I have created the table logdata like this. But, I am getting the following error.

```
create 'logdata', {NAME => ' m', BLOOMFILTER => 'NONE', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '3', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS =>'0', TTL => '2147483647', BLOCKSIZE=> '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}

13/09/23 12:57:19 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201309231115_0025_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 755 actions: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.NoSuchColumnFamilyException: Column family  m does not exist in region logdata,,1379920697845.30fce8bcc99bf9ed321720496a3ec498. in table 'logdata', {NAME => 'm', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'NONE', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', VERSIONS => '3', TTL => '2147483647', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'false', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', ENCODE_ON_DISK => 'true', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.multi(HRegionServer.java:3773)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Server.call(WritableRpcEngine.java:320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseServer$Handler.run(HBaseServer.java:1426)
: 755 times, servers with issues: master:60020, 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.processBatchCallback(HConnectionManager.java:1674)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.processBatch(HConnectionManager.java:1450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.flushCommits(HTable.java:916)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.close(HTable.java:953)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat$TableRecordWriter.close(TableOutputFormat.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:651)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:766)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)

13/09/23 12:57:29 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201309231115_0025_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 755 actions: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.NoSuchColumnFamilyException: Column family  m does not exist in region logdata,,1379920697845.30fce8bcc99bf9ed321720496a3ec498. in table 'logdata', {NAME => 'm', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'NONE', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', VERSIONS => '3', TTL => '2147483647', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'false', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', ENCODE_ON_DISK => 'true', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.multi(HRegionServer.java:3773)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Server.call(WritableRpcEngine.java:320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseServer$Handler.run(HBaseServer.java:1426)
: 755 times, servers with issues: master:60020, 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.processBatchCallback(HConnectionManager.java:1674)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.processBatch(HConnectionManager.java:1450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.flushCommits(HTable.java:916)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.close(HTable.java:953)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat$TableRecordWriter.close(TableOutputFormat.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:651)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:766)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)

13/09/23 12:57:38 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201309231115_0025_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 755 actions: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.NoSuchColumnFamilyException: Column family  m does not exist in region logdata,,1379920697845.30fce8bcc99bf9ed321720496a3ec498. in table 'logdata', {NAME => 'm', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'NONE', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', VERSIONS => '3', TTL => '2147483647', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'false', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', ENCODE_ON_DISK => 'true', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.multi(HRegionServer.java:3773)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Server.call(WritableRpcEngine.java:320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseServer$Handler.run(HBaseServer.java:1426)
: 755 times, servers with issues: master:60020, 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.processBatchCallback(HConnectionManager.java:1674)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.processBatch(HConnectionManager.java:1450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.flushCommits(HTable.java:916)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.close(HTable.java:953)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat$TableRecordWriter.close(TableOutputFormat.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:651)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:766)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)

13/09/23 12:57:53 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201309231115_0025
13/09/23 12:57:53 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 7
13/09/23 12:57:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
13/09/23 12:57:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=34605
13/09/23 12:57:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
13/09/23 12:57:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
13/09/23 12:57:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Rack-local map tasks=4
13/09/23 12:57:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=4
13/09/23 12:57:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=0
13/09/23 12:57:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Failed map tasks=1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually i am using hive-0.9.0. Which has a bug

```
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3243.
```

So, while creating the table **SerDe of HBaseStorageHandler doesn't ignore white space between comma and column family**. Hence you need to remove the white spaces. Then it will work fine.

Answer (score 5):

Use the **[copyTable](http://hbase.apache.org/book/ops_mgt.html#copytable)** command. Example :

```
$ bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.CopyTable --new.name=logdata hbasetest
```

Comment: First of all thanx tariq. But, Now i am getting the error which i have edited in my question. Could you please tell me what's creating the issue?

Comment: Could you please show me the output of **describe 'logdata'**??

Comment: Actually data was not copied. When i executed the command "hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.CopyTable --new.name=logdata hbasetest". It gave me the error which i have updated in my question. Also, do we need to create the table before you copy the data? This command doesn't create on its own.

Comment: You need to create the table with same structure before you copy data.

Comment: What you suggested works if i create another table from hive like hivetest. But, if i create the table using hbase shell with the same schema. It doesn't copy the data and throws that above exception. So, is there any way i can overcome from this problem?

Comment: Do you know how to schedule mapreduce task of CopyTable to not default application queue on hadoop environment?