# Hbase CopyTable copy specific column from different columnfamilies to new table

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hadoop2

I have a table in Hbase `"aks:myprofiles`"

which have two column families i and s

column family i have - 5 column `{ic1,ic2,ic3,ic4,ic5}`

column family s have - 5 column `{sc1,sc2,sc3,sc4,sc5}`

```
Describe "aks:myprofiles"

NAME => 'i', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', COMPRESSION => 'SNAPPY', VERSIONS => '1', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => 'FOREVER',
KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}
{NAME => 's', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW',    REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', COMPRESSION => 'SNAPPY', VERSIONS => '1', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => 'FOREVER',
KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}
```

I want to copy table data to another table of all the version of the 
ic1, ic2 and sc1 ,sc2 to a new table

**Not for all column I want all the version of  specific column**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy Data from one hbase table to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942895/copy-data-from-one-hbase-table-to-another)

Comment: @usersx : check my answer. please feel free to ask questions

Comment: @Rijulsahu That was totally different I dont want to copy all version of all column 
i want all version of specific columns

Answer (score 1):

#### Below is the way you can use `CopyTable`. if you want to customize the versions of specific columns you can create custom mapreduce program by extending [`CopyTable`](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/7572e96e3abdc6636b53df3ca8738f467334a9ea/hbase-server/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/CopyTable.java) its not possible as it is with `CopyTable` mapreduce job.

If you dig deep in to the code you will understand several options.
See [CopyTable](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/7572e96e3abdc6636b53df3ca8738f467334a9ea/hbase-server/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/CopyTable.java) `printusage` method

#### Below is example usage :

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.CopyTable --starttime=1265875194289 --endtime=1265878794289 --peer.adr=server1,server2,server3:2181:/hbase --families=myOldCf:myNewCf,cf2,cf3 TestTable
```

---

```
/*
   * @param errorMsg Error message.  Can be null.
   */
  private static void printUsage(final String errorMsg) {
    if (errorMsg != null && errorMsg.length() > 0) {
      System.err.println("ERROR: " + errorMsg);
    }
    System.err.println("Usage: CopyTable [general options] [--starttime=X] [--endtime=Y] " +
        "[--new.name=NEW] [--peer.adr=ADR] <tablename>");
    System.err.println();
    System.err.println("Options:");
    System.err.println(" rs.class     hbase.regionserver.class of the peer cluster");
    System.err.println("              specify if different from current cluster");
    System.err.println(" rs.impl      hbase.regionserver.impl of the peer cluster");
    System.err.println(" startrow     the start row");
    System.err.println(" stoprow      the stop row");
    System.err.println(" starttime    beginning of the time range (unixtime in millis)");
    System.err.println("              without endtime means from starttime to forever");
    System.err.println(" endtime      end of the time range.  Ignored if no starttime specified.");
    System.err.println(" versions     number of cell versions to copy");
    System.err.println(" new.name     new table's name");
    System.err.println(" peer.adr     Address of the peer cluster given in the format");
    System.err.println("              hbase.zookeeper.quorum:hbase.zookeeper.client"
        + ".port:zookeeper.znode.parent");
    System.err.println(" families     comma-separated list of families to copy");
    System.err.println("              To copy from cf1 to cf2, give sourceCfName:destCfName. ");
    System.err.println("              To keep the same name, just give \"cfName\"");
    System.err.println(" all.cells    also copy delete markers and deleted cells");
    System.err.println(" bulkload     Write input into HFiles and bulk load to the destination "
        + "table");
    System.err.println();
    System.err.println("Args:");
    System.err.println(" tablename    Name of the table to copy");
    System.err.println();
    System.err.println("Examples:");
    System.err.println(" To copy 'TestTable' to a cluster that uses replication for a 1 hour window:");
    System.err.println(" $ hbase " +
        "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.CopyTable --starttime=1265875194289 --endtime=1265878794289 " +
        "--peer.adr=server1,server2,server3:2181:/hbase --families=myOldCf:myNewCf,cf2,cf3 TestTable ");
    System.err.println("For performance consider the following general option:\n"
        + "  It is recommended that you set the following to >=100. A higher value uses more memory but\n"
        + "  decreases the round trip time to the server and may increase performance.\n"
        + "    -Dhbase.client.scanner.caching=100\n"
        + "  The following should always be set to false, to prevent writing data twice, which may produce \n"
        + "  inaccurate results.\n"
        + "    -Dmapreduce.map.speculative=false");
  }
```

Comment: yes the number of version was never a question the question is to all version of some specific columns

Comment: understood question, but giving a pointer to versions parameter present. Also see my first line "if you want to customize the versions of specific columns you can create custom mapreduce program by extending CopyTable" its not possible as it is with `CopyTable` mapreduce job. Hope that clarifies

Comment: yes your answer is very correct for the problem, and one more things there is not any hard and fast that I only have to use copyTable , if there is any other possible or good solution that will be helpful

Comment: you can take the `CopyTable` mapreduce job code which I pointed in the link and play with that for your requirement. Currently I don't have mapreduce hbase environement to write code and demonstrate. If you are okay with answer above, please vote-up/accept as owner. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

We can copy all versions of specific columns (say `ic1, ic2, ic3`) from table `a` to table `b` in the following manner :

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.CopyTable --versions=vers --families=ic1,ic2 --new.name=b a
```

Where `vers` is the maximum number of versions that you need to be copied.

For all the other columns, the `--versions` option can be excluded, i.e. the following command can be run

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.CopyTable --new.name=b a
```

Comment: there are two column family i and s and  ic1 and ic2 are column which i need to copy ic1 is not a column family

Answer (score 0):

you can use [copyTable](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#copy.table)

```
$ bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.CopyTable --new.name=new_table_name myprofiles
```

Comment: you must specify name of the column families to be copied, --families:colFam